# Pixate and AutoLayout

Tags: ios, pixate

I am looking into using Pixate with iOS 7/8 app.

- Does it work with autolayout?
- Does it support it fully or are there conflicts?

I use AutoLayout extensively so I want to make sure it works.

- Are there other CSS frameworks for iOS that work with AutoLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parts of Pixate Freestyle that specify style **do not conflict** with Auto Layout. Some lesser known pieces of Pixate let you specify positioning and such, and I suspect that Auto Layout constraints will override what's in your Pixate CSS.

But if you're just using Pixate for style, you're good. I styled an entire Auto Layout app with no problems.